# IE non-compatibility adds in unwanted text when saving data

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, qtip

I have a problem in IE Non-compatibility mode. I have an editorContent container that starts off as follows.

```
  <div id="p1" class="paragraph">This is the first paragraph </div>
```

However when I press a button extra stuff is added. At the moment Chrome,FF and IE compatibility mode works. However when I use non-compatibility mode it just does not work. After using it in Chrome it looks like this.

```
           <div id="p1" class="paragraph qTip triangle-isosceles-blue" style="color: black; font-size: 110%; padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px; " title="marked">
           This is the first paragraph
          </div>
```

This works fine and as intended, however when I execute the same function in IE Non-compatibility view I get the following.

```
  <DIV aria-hidden=true style="PADDING-LEFT: 10px; BACKGROUND: none transparent scroll repeat 0% 0%; COLOR: black; FONT-SIZE: 110%" id=p1 class="paragraph qTip triangle-isosceles-blue" title="marked" sizcache="387" sizset="0">
  <P>This is the first paragraph</P></DIV>
```

This, as you can see,is completely different then above. Below is the function called when I press the button.
$set in this case, is the div id p1.

```
   $('#add2').click(function() {
          classList = "marked";
          $set.addClass ( "qTip triangle-isosceles-blue ") ;
            $set.attr('title', "marked");

            $('.qTip').qtip({
                suppress: false,
                style: {
                    classes: 'ui-tooltip-green ui-tooltip-shadow'
                }
            });
        });
```

Any help on why this is happening will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The attributes sizcache and sizset are used by [jQuery core](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jquery-en/I4Kmahzp7fY).